# Prove or disprove the following statement. $7 \ | \ (x^3 + x^2 + x + 2)$, where $x$ is an odd integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

We're learning about modulus and division (Discrete mathematics and proofs course).  I'm not exactly sure how to tackle this sort of problem, is there some sort of property of cubic functions involving odd or even results that will tell us if it's divisible by $7$ or not?

Comment: Well, checking $x=1$ will show you that it isn't always true. (Are you sure you got the polynomial right?)

Comment: And if it works for a given $x$, it should work for $x+7$ (given that the polynomial has integer coefficients). Therefore odd/even would not enter the argument at all. So something's wrong with the polynomial/function that you described. Mind you, IMHO it would be better to include the description of the function in the question body as well.

Comment: This expression will not be divisible by 7.

Answer (score 4):

Checking the results modulo $7$ for any $x$ will show that $7$ doesn't divide $x^3 + x^2 + x + 2$ for any integer $x$.

Performing arithmetic $\pmod 7$, we'll only need to check $x$ values from $0$ to $6$.

If $x = 0 \pmod 7$, $x^3 + x^2 + x + 2 \pmod 7 = 2$

If $x = 1 \pmod 7$, $x^3 + x^2 + x + 2 \pmod 7 = 5$

If $x = 2 \pmod 7$, $x^3 + x^2 + x + 2 \pmod 7 = 8 + 4 + 2 + 2 \pmod 7 = 2$

If $x = 3 \pmod 7$, $x^3 + x^2 + x + 2 \pmod 7 = 27 + 9 + 3 + 2 \pmod 7 = 6$

If $x = 4 \pmod 7$, $x^3 + x^2 + x + 2 \pmod 7 = 64 + 16 + 4 + 2 \pmod 7 = 2$

If $x = 5 \pmod 7$, $x^3 + x^2 + x + 2 \pmod 7 = 125 + 25 + 5 + 2 \pmod 7 = 3$

If $x = 6 \pmod 7$, $x^3 + x^2 + x + 2 \pmod 7 = 216 + 36 + 6 + 2 \pmod 7 = 1$

We didn't find any $0$ results $\pmod 7$, so no integer value of $x$, odd or otherwise, can make the expression $x^3 + x^2 + x + 2$ divisible by $7$.